# How can I Generate a time series with Hadoop?

Tags: date, hadoop, time-series, sequence

What's the easiest way to generate a time series with Hadoop (or pig or Hive)?, Or where can I get information on the proper functions?

For example I want to generate a 1sec sequence from 00:00:00 01/01/2000  to  23:59:59 31/12/2010.

With other programs, such as R, is quite simple because they have many functions to work with dates and times.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can write a mapper with an empty map() method. In the cleanup() method use any of several java packages (e.g. Joda) to help iterate over and format the timestamps before writing them to the context.

Answer (score 0):

When you find it so simple with R, why don't you make use of [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/streaming.html)? :)

AFAIK, there is no OOTB feature which does this. As you have already mentioned, R has many cool builtin functions which you can use in your streaming MR jobs.

Comment: Hi. Because I would like to generate (and work with) very large series (10 or 100 times larger than the example, even several series at once), that cannot fit in memory, that's why I want to try with hadoop.

Comment: Hello. Hadoop streaming is nothing but Hadoop's MapReduce. It's just that you  write your job in some non-java language.